# Prevent VSCode from unfolding code when cursor moves past folded section

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to prevent VSCode from unfolding a folded code section if I move past it with my cursor using the arrow keys?

A common workflow I have coming from Atom is to fold parts of my code, then move my cursor down below the folded sections to get to later sections of a file. If I do this in VSCode, the folded section will unfold as soon as my cursor crosses the top of the section. I want it to move past it instead.

Here's an example:

[image]

I searched my prefs and Google for a setting, but couldn't find one.

Comment: Coming back to this – disabling my Vim extension seems to fix it. Still digging.

Comment: Hi Sam. Yes, if you're using the vim extension you will incur in this bug. There's an [issue](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/pull/1552) here and another answer on SO that you might find useful [here](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/pull/1552) but bottom line is that it's a known bug that still looks not 100% fixed

Comment: Thanks Nobita, I literally found this just as you submitted! The fix works great.

Comment: This is also an issue when using neovim with VSCode. See the open issue [here](https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/issues/58).

The most viable [workaround](https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/issues/58#issuecomment-630551787) mentioned in that issue is to set `nmap j gj` and `nmap k gk` in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My Google-fu failed me when I first opened this but there's plenty of discussion around it, and a fix.

- [Issue](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/1004)
- [Temp fix issue](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/pull/1552)

The FAQ for the VSCodeVim extension also says this:

> - Moving j/k over folds opens up the folds
>
> Try setting vim.foldfix to true. This is a hack; it works fine, but there are side effects (see issue#22276).

The fix is working great for me!! Very happy to have solved this.

Comment: It's not solved :-( I'm using <line number> + G to escape auto unfolding at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's been driving me crazy. Can't wait till there's an official fix; until then I'm glad this at least fixes the `k`/`j` navigation.